# Web Content Management how to find all the descendants of a content

Tags: wcm, ibm-wcm

I want to display all the descendant contents within a site area in IBM WCM. 
But right now, I could only find API to find a certain item, but not all the descendants of that content.
The API for this is findAllByPath API:

```
DocumentIdIterator findAllByPath(java.lang.String namePath,
                             DocumentType documentType,
                             int workflowStatusFilter,
                             DocumentLibrary[] documentLibraries)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you solved this but you can use the query service to return children for a given parent query

Comment: yes, I used                                                              
DocumentIdIterator docIdt = siteArea.getDirectChildren(Workspace.WORKFLOWSTATUS_PUBLISHED | Workspace.WORKFLOWSTATUS_DRAFT | Workspace.WORKFLOWSTATUS_EXPIRED);